# validation engine ajax inline validation not functional

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validation-engine

I am currently implementing validations and we badly need ajax inline validation working with validation engine.
I downloaded the newest version and demos from github. And I think there is an js error. Please have a look at the example that exactly reproduces the error I get in my own code.

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoAjaxInlinePHP.html

Please run it in firefox with firebug open, enter the right name (karnius), you can clearly see that an ajax request is performed that returns ["user",true], but there is a js error: 
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #user']
So the validation is blocked and never actually completed.

I had the same error with my own form, just another field.

Before I had another version of validation engine that worked, but showed a green promt in case of errors that was covering the field and then animating upwards...

Can anyone point me to a functional version of validation engine or better to a functional example of ajax inline validation?

Comment: i am facing the same problem with the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of `jquery.validationEngine.js` it seems like the following line has an extra `"]"`.

```
var errorField = $("#"+ errorFieldId +"']").eq(0);
```

The above line is line no. 1353 in the version of jve i am using. To fix the error just lookup for this line in `jquery.validationEngine.js` and change it to the following.

```
var errorField = $("#"+ errorFieldId).eq(0);
```